# Projection of vector spaces defined by Fourier expansion over all basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a nontrivial subspace of vector space $U$ with a positive definite scalar product. $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a orthogonal basis for $V$. I am trying to show that a mapping $P:U\to U$ given by the Fourier expansion $$P(u)=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(v_i,u)}{(v_i,v_i)}v_i \hspace{1cm} \text{ for all } u\in U$$
is a projection of $U$ along $V^\perp$ onto $V$.

I see how the interior of this sum represents the projection of a vector $u$ onto $v$ but am not sure how this is along $v^\perp$ and moreso how to show this is a projection for the whole vector spaces?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It's enough to prove that $P(v)=v$ if $v\in V$ and $P(u)=0$ if $u\perp V$.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I see why this works now since we are given an orthogonal basis in $V$.